# Nested for loop unexpected output

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been trying to make a nested for loop, but for some reason the inside one only loops once and I can't figure out why. I've already reduced my code to the bare minimum just to figure out whats happening:

```
pupil = db.session.query(Pupil).all()
result = db.session.query(Pupil_OLD).all()
for row in pupil:
    for sublist in result:   
        print("sublist"+str(sublist.PUPIL_ID))
    print("pupil"+str(row.PUPIL_ID))
```

This produces:

```
pupil1
sublist1
sublist2
sublist3
pupil2
pupil3
```

While it should produce

```
pupil1
sublist1
sublist2
sublist3
pupil2
sublist1
sublist2
sublist3
pupil3
sublist1
sublist2
sublist3
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does ```db.session.query(Pupil_OLD).all()``` return?

Comment: My guess is that by doing `for sublist in result:` you are consuming the query.

Comment: Is this SQLAlchemy?

Comment: in second line check the result for use simple print to see what is the contents of it. your problem relate to result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `result` is a generator which is reaching the end.

You can reset it like so:

```
pupil = db.session.query(Pupil).all()
for row in pupil:
    result = db.session.query(Pupil_OLD).all()
    for sublist in result:   
        print("sublist"+str(sublist.PUPIL_ID))
    print("pupil"+str(row.PUPIL_ID))
```

Converting it to a list is another option, but you'd be missing out on cool generators ;)

My love for generator's aside, if resetting it means re-querying a database, you might be better off with the list.

Comment: It is not very efficient to do the same query over and over for each pupil.

Comment: Probably depends if your constraints are speed or memory, but I agree that repeating the query is inefficient.

Comment: If memory is an issue then the results are very large and dumping it to disk memory would solve both problems.

Comment: Yeah, and you'd probably want to use a generator to dump it to disk, and a generator each time you want to read it.

Comment: I had never heard of a generator until now and the fact that you can exhaust it. I thought I was dealing with lists. I've converted the result generator to a list and now it works. Querying the database every time would be inefficient indeed. Time to do some reading on generators :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You should rather do something like

```
pupil = db.session.query(Pupil).all()
result = list(db.session.query(Pupil_OLD).all())
```

So the result of `db.session.query(Pupil_OLD).all()` which appears to be a generator, is converted to a list which won't be consumed like your generator is.